# How can I allow an image to be touched on a scroll view?

Tags: objective-c, uitouch

In my program, I use a scroll view as the background view. Then, I add several images on the scroll view. Also, I allow the users to touch the image in order to trigger some actions. However, the images attached on the scroll view cannot be detected when they were touched. I use the following code my the touch event:

```
UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

Did I do something wrong? How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to track touches, and also set `myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES`, since the default is no for imageviews.

If you want to detect a tap on the image you can do this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlesSingleTap:)];
        [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and implement your selector:

```
- (void)handlesSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Handle touch
}
```

Comment: I have set the thing that you say. However, there is no respond when I touch the image. I think the simulator is just detect that I touch the scroll view only, but not the image. Also, I have tried to move the image outside the scroll view, then it works. How it comes?

Comment: @PeterLam Can you post your code?, I am using this code on a scrollview and it is working fine.

Comment: In the .h file, I create 
IBOutLet UIImageView*img1; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutLet UIImageView*img1; 
at the .m file, I create 
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{ UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; if ([ touch view] == img1){ 
//code is here } 
ViewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
img1.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}

I have checked this the program cannot run the function touchesBegan{}